# How to append an ul using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, arrays

So I have an unordered list in my html code and let's say I wanna add names to it from javascript using Jquery

let Names = ['Richard', 'Bob', 'John']

[image: Here's how I tried]

I'm still a beginner so there's probably a lot that I missed.

Why is this isn't working?

[image: Here is a pciture from my html code]

Comment: Please don't post images of your code, but post the actual code.

Comment: The [documentation for `.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) or the [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com) will help with your problem

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as a picture as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your actual code, only thing I can think of that is wrong is your missing the `"` multiple places.

Use :

```
Names.forEach((name) => {
  $("ul").append("<li>" + name + "</li>")
});
```

**Demo**

```js
let Names = ['Richard', 'Bob', 'John']

Names.forEach((name) => {
  $("ul").append("<li>" + name + "</li>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks